# Calculating standard deviation of last N elements of in a pine series

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Try to calculate the standard deviation of last 5 elements of a series
below is the implementation I copied from TradingView official's ADX implementation

```
//@version=4
study(title="DMI movement out of 2SD in last 10 points", shorttitle="StrategyX", format=format.price, precision=4, resolution="")
lensig = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len = input(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")

up = change(high)
down = -change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = rma(tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)
```

What I was trying to do is to get the standard deviation of the latest 5 plus (DMI+) data points, I tried multiple approaches..

1. Create an array, then push in the data point one by one

But turned out I can't get the data point from the `plus` series. It should return a variable (the fifth last element) but not another series (according to the official doc: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_[]](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_%5B%5D))

```
plus[5] // do not understand why it is still a series but not a float
```

2. Convert Series to array, then do `reverse` and `slice`

which again failed as there is no way to convert series to array

any help would be greatly appreciated :pray thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the built-in `stdev` function?

```
plus2StDev = 2 * stdev(plus, 5)
plot(plus2StDev)
```

*But turned out I can't the data point from the plus series*
Could be during the early stages of runtime the data doesn't exists yet, for example on the first bar there is no past values of *plus* series. You can use `nz` function to safely access the series history data - `nz(plus[5])`.

custom stdev function shared by tradingview user alexgrover:

```
f_stdev(src, length) => length == 1 ? 0 : sqrt(sma(pow(src, 2), length) - pow(sma(src, length), 2)) 
plus2StDev = 2 * f_stdev(plus, 5)
plot(plus2StDev)
```

Comment: thanks. yes I know, there is a `stdev` func in pine language. but the problem is mainly about can't not get a subarray / slice of the series. I am expecting `plus[5]` to be a variable but not another series. according to the doc: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_[]

Comment: According to the doc it will return a series. As far as I understand pine - every variable becomes a series during runtime. Even if you'll try to create a constant with one-time initialization with 'var' keyword you still can index it with history reference operator '[]'.

Comment: TV user alexgrover shared a custom stdev function written in pine. Not sure, but this could help to accomplish your goal (updated the answer)