# Plot STD Dev in Pinescript with custom parameters

Tags: pine-script

Can anyone let me know how to plot STD Dev in Pinescript using custom parameters as mentioned below

Period : 20
Multiplier : 4
Source : Close

IS this correct
x = 4 * stdev(close, 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct.
You could also make `input()` variables for those variables.
It'll be more convenient to change them, rather than hard-code them.
For more information, see the answer to this question:
[Calculating standard deviation of last N elements of in a pine series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149472/calculating-standard-deviation-of-last-n-elements-of-in-a-pine-series)
It contains a custom implementation of a standard deviation calculation.