# How to calculate the standard deviation in in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, indicator, expert-advisor

I just came across pine script now and want to create a simple indicator. I am not a programmer so it’s not native to me.

The code would calculate the average values of the high-low for the last 20 bars. The variable avgRange would be used to store the average. So the function I used to calculate simple moving average was: `ta.sma(`

I want to calculate the standard deviation of the high-low over each of the last 20 bars. I would name the variable StDev. What function do I use for that? Is it `ta.cstd(`?

Lastly, I want to find the coefficient of variation(I named the variable CoffVar) and plot it’s value.

So the code I wrote so far is below. I left the standard deviation blank because I don’t know what to fill in there.

`BarRange()=>high-low`
`avgRange=ta.sma(BarRange(),20)`
`StDev=…….`
`CoffVar=StDev/avgRange*100`
`plot(CoffVar)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating standard deviation of last N elements of in a pine series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149472/calculating-standard-deviation-of-last-n-elements-of-in-a-pine-series)

Answer (score 0):

pine script already has a built in function in the technical analysis library (`ta.stdev`). you will just need to enter the source (in your case hl2 is the mid point of the bar) and the number of bars:

```
ta.stdev(hl2, 20)
```